# How do I solve this formalized argument by drawing conclusions from inference rules?

Tags: logic

I am given a conclusion and three premises, but I have to draw more inference rules from the three premises in order to prove the conclusion is in fact true. How do I draw the conclusion from the premises via inferences?

```
    C:         P  =  Q
    -------------------------
    P1:        P  >  ~R
    P2:       ~Q  >  R
    P3:        P  v  ~Q
```

Comment: Are you sure you typed that correctly? The conclusion doesn't follow. For example if P=F and Q=T then all of the premises are true but the conclusion is false.

Comment: It's not a truth table, but a draw from inferences.

Comment: Yes but what I wrote means the conclusion cannot be derived from the premises. Are you sure it's typed correctly?

Comment: You were right, it was not typed correctly, how about now?

Answer (score 2):

To prove the equivalence `P = Q` we must prove `P > Q` and `Q > P`. The first is not very hard, the second is a bit tricky.

Here it is:

```
1.  | P           assumption
2.  | P > ~R      P1
3.  | ~R          1,2
4.  | | ~Q        assumption
5.  | | ~Q > R    P2
6.  | | R         4,5
7.  | | R * ~R    3,6
8.  | ~~Q         4-7
9.  | Q           8
10. P > Q         1-9
11. | Q           assumption
12. | | ~Q        assumption
13. | | | ~P      assumption
14. | | | Q * ~Q  11,12
15. | | ~~P       13-14
16. | | P         15
17. | ~Q > P      12-16
18. | | P         assumption
19. | | P         18
20. | P > P       18-19
21. | P v ~Q      P3
22. | P           17,20,21
23. Q > P         11-22
24  P = Q         10,23
```

Comment: How did you do that? That is just amazing!

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternate proof to the one provided by Eliran. As Eliran mentioned,

> To prove the equivalence P = Q we must prove P > Q and Q > P.

[image]

To prove *P ↔ Q*, that is (P = Q), from the three premises, I first show that *Q → P* on lines 4 to 8. I had to take a detour with a subproof on lines 5 to 6 since I do not have a double-negation introduction rule in this [proof checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/), but it is easy to derive what is needed with a subproof. I do have disjunctive syllogism (DS) and so take advantage of that on line 8 to derive *P*.

Next I show that *P → Q*. This uses modus tollens (MT) on line 11 and double-negation elimination (DNE) on line 12.

For more information on these rules see *forallx* cited below. In particular disjunctive syllogism (DS) is in section 16.2. Modus tollens (MT) is in 16.3. Double-negation elimination (DNE) is in 16.4.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/